# Android multiple vertical seekBars

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar

I'm trying to design a view for Android app that is supposed to have 2 vertical SeekBars, here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/control_view_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarL"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarR"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the android studio's preview and on a device it looks just fine, but whenever I try to change the position of the left `SeekBar`, the right one gets triggered instead. No matter where I put my thumb on, the only right one reacts. Does anyone ever get this strange behavior?

Comment: just try by removing the weight

Comment: It does not help, I've already tried it

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this happens (it is strange) but I know how to repair it. Don't put SeekBars in the same container, put it in `FrameLayout` and it will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/control_view_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBarR"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rotation="270" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBarL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rotation="270" />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```